# How to change string codification from chinese to default or English in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I need to get a path from two different machine/pc, one of them is with English environment and the other with Chinese environment.

I have a project into our database with this name: Defaults侇侚

If I open my database the name is display like this: [image]

Is the last one.

My problem is, when I'm going on the English machine/pc I receive in my application this String: `"c:\Restore\20190213140908\Defaults" & ChrW(129) & "î" & ChrW(129) & "ù\Defaults" & ChrW(129) & "î" & ChrW(129) & "ù"`
Everything is ok, my function return true.

But when I'm going on the Chinese machine/pc I receive this type of string:`"c:\Restore\20190213142118\Defaults侇侚\Defaults侇侚"` and my function doesn't work.

My question is how it's posible to convert this string:

```
"c:\Restore\20190213142118\Defaults侇侚\Defaults侇侚"
```

to

```
"c:\Restore\20190213140908\Defaults" & ChrW(129) & "î" & ChrW(129) & "ù\Defaults" & ChrW(129) & "î" & ChrW(129) & "ù"
```

Note: For this database is not possible to change the unicode.

Comment: Would it be of any help if we could get the function to work with "c:\Restore\20190213142118\Defaults侇侚\Defaults侇侚"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, it's a long function, I create an object like this: objMillDBProj = CreateObject("Mil.Project") and after that I send the string like:  objMillDBProj.ReadInfFile(strmRestorePath, strTmpProject, strTmpUser, dblQuota) where strmRestorePath is my Path.

Comment: 1) If you check if the [file exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.7.2) in your program, does the check work with the Chinese characters? 2) I notice you use `CreateObject` - is this definitely a VB.NET program or is it VBA (or VB6) program? 3) Is the `Mil.Project` something you have control of?

Comment: Are you sure your program is **VB.NET**? It looks rather like VBScript or VBA or VB6

Comment: What is the data type of column `NAME`? What is the character set of your database (check with `SELECT * 
    FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');` Which driver do you use?

Comment: I would suppose `c:\Restore\20190213142118\Defaults侇侚\Defaults侇侚` would be the correct string rather than `"c:\Restore\20190213140908\Defaults" & ChrW(129) & "î" & ChrW(129) & "ù\Defaults" & ChrW(129) & "î" & ChrW(129) & "ù"`. Looks like you do some crazy stuff with junk data.

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT DUMP(NAME, 1016)`?